# The long Bangla characters paragraph does not stored in MySQL database but long English paragraph does

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am inserting data into database using HTML form. The Long Bangla characters paragraph(450 words) does not insert into MySQL database but same length English characters paragraph inserted.

I have tested short Bangla paragraph(50 words). It was inserted properly.

Comment: Highly likely that a character contained somewhere within the text requires escaping, and as such is killing the insert statement

Comment: Is a row inserted, but the text column is empty?  Or is the column partially there?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Also, could you dump the hex of the first few characters; I would like to check that the 50-word text was stored correctly.  `SELECT LEFT(HEX(col), 20) ...`  I would expect to see a pattern:  `E0xxyyE0....`